# Convert color photos of documents to good black-and-white (bitonal) images?

Tags: linux, images, colors, processing, bitmaps

Since I don't have a copier or scanner, I'm using an 8 megapixel camera to copy documents.  This works pretty well except they need a lot of processing afterward.  I'd like to get from a photo to a bitmap, but using

```
djpeg -grayscale -pnm photo.jpg |
pgmtopbm -threshold -value XXX
```

does not work so well, for two reasons:

1. It's hard to guess what XXX should be, and XXX is different for different photos.
2. Illumination varies, and sometimes a single threshold isn't what's right for the image.

How can I do better?  The ideal solution will be fully automatic command-line program that I can run on Linux.  (I have already written a program to remove dark pixels from the edges of images.)

NOTE: I really want a *bitmap*, that's just black and white pixels.  No grayscale, no dithering.

Comment: Similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/107313/software-to-clean-up-photos-of-whiteboards-and-documents/

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/how-do-you-binarize-a-colored-image || Requiring ImageMagick: http://superuser.com/questions/405686/how-to-convert-a-photo-to-a-black-and-white-image-by-imagemagick

Answer (score 4):

The best thing I've found in three years is the `mkbitmap` program that ships with [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

**`-monochrome`**

This option uses some smart dithering and generates very visible output:

```
convert -monochrome in.png out.png
```

Documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome

Compare that to a simpler `-threshold 50` transform:

```
convert -threshold 50 in.png out.png
```

which loses most of the image.

Concrete example from: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/galex/pia15416.html

```
wget -O orig.jpg http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/650137main_pia15416b-43_full.jpg
# Downsize to 400 height to have a reasonable file size for upload here.
convert orig.jpg -resize x400 in.jpg
convert -monochrome in.jpg out.jpg
convert -threshold 50 in.jpg threshold-50.jpg
```

in.jpg

[image]

out.jpg

[image]

threshold-50.jpg

[image]

Related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861025/how-to-convert-an-image-to-1bit-px-binary-bitmap-with-imagemagick-or-rmagick
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9868/convert-an-image-from-grayscale-to-binary
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/how-do-you-binarize-a-colored-image

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10, ImageMagick 6.9.10.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Gimp supports some [command-line batch processing](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).  You might be able to give that a shot, since desaturating will probably behave like you'd expect with varying brightness in your images.

Comment: I'd be happy to try it; can you suggest which among the many hundreds of GIMP transformations might be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your camera. Many modern digital cameras have the ability to take B&W photos directly.

Comment: I'm looking for bitonal, not greyscale.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to grayscale / desaturating will preserve most of the noise too. The GIMP has a Threshold filter (under the Color menu) that eliminates the noise, and works very well for line-art and plain black scanned text.

I'm not too clued up on the batch scripting myself, but it sounds like a good idea to use the Threshold with it.

Edit: Since you have Linux as a tag, have a look at [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/), batch photo manipulations. It has filters to adjust the contrast and brightness too. It's in the Ubuntu repos (if you use that distro)

Comment: OK, I checked out Threshold, and it does exactly what `pgmtopbm` does.  If I wanted to adjust each page by hand, it would be great, but I really don't.  At it completely doesn't solve the problem that I really need different thresholds in different parts of the image.  Still, yours was the answer that most closely identified what GIMP can and can't do, so +1.  P.S. It took me several *minutes* to find the thing among the goddamned menus.

Comment: Apart from eyeballing the image, I can't say how to calculate the threshold values per image. Wow I'm stumped. Perhaps auto-adjusting the light levels first will put all images on the 'same level', and a common threshold value will then work?