# How to convert a photo to a black and white image by ImageMagick?

Tags: linux, images, jpeg, imagemagick

How can I convert a JPEG photo to black and white (not grayscale) image like output of a FAX scanner, by ImageMagick?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/how-do-you-binarize-a-colored-image

Comment: No ImageMagick requirement: http://superuser.com/questions/75373/convert-color-photos-of-documents-to-good-black-and-white-bitonal-images

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11279):

However, if you want two colors only (black and white), then you need to threshold. For example, to select the color where above will be white and below will be black.

> `convert <input> -threshold xx% <output>`

where xx is in range 0-100 (for percent).

Answer (score 19):

Dithering is clearer and more fax-like than a threshold cutoff:

```
convert <input> -monochrome <output>
```

For a less contrasty but more information-preserving kind of dithering, use:

```
convert <input> -remap pattern:gray50 <output>
```

[(Docs)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome)

Comment: Note that if the output looks low-quality, you may need to set the density higher using the flag `-density 150` (the 150 is a dpi value)

Comment: Good answer as it gives 2 options that produce different output and you can choose the best result

Answer (score 11):

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708480/4098390):

If you have imagemagick installed:

true grayscale only:

```
convert source.jpg -colorspace Gray destination.jpg
```

true black and white:

```
convert source.jpg -monochrome destination.jpg
```

separate into gray channels:

```
convert source.jpg -separate destination.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Netpbm's *pamthreshold* is a much faster and more flexible solution.

For TIFF files, I do

```
 $ tifftopnm test.tiff | pamthreshold | pamtotiff > bitonal.tiff
```

For Jpeg files you can do

```
$ jpegtopnm test.jpeg | pamthreshold | pamtotiff > bitonal.tiff
```

*Pamthreshold* is rather powerful (take a look at its man page).