# Converting from color to true black and white in ImageMagick?

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

I have seen how to convert a picture from color to grayscale [in this Super User question and answer thread](https://superuser.com/questions/405686/how-to-convert-a-photo-to-a-black-and-white-image-by-imagemagick).  However, grayscale is not black and white.

Simply put, if a field has color, I want to convert it to black.  All other areas should be white.  So, if a line 6 pixels thick is orange, the other thread's answer will turn the line gray.  The line should be turned solid black.

However, is there a way to convert anything of any color at all (not white) to black?

I am working with Engineering prints, and it simply needs to be black or white. Gray does not work, because certain color lines become “gray” lines.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your question is.

Comment: Why does the answer in the linked question not work for you?

Comment: @DavidPostill, please see my updated question.  How to convert a solid orange line to a solid black line (not a solid gray line).  I know gray is just black pixels mixed with white pixels, but this is not where I want it to go...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### How do I convert from color to true black and white?

> If a field has color, I want to convert it to black.

Use the following command:

```
convert <input> -negate -threshold 0 -negate <output>
```

---

#### Threshold Dithering Methods

> **Threshold Images**
>
> The simplest method of converting an image into black and white bitmap
>   (to color) image is to use `-threshold`. This is actually a simple
>   mathematical operator that just provides a cut-off value. Anything
>   equal to or below that value becomes black, while anything larger
>   becomes white.

...

> If you actually want to convert all non-pure white colors to black,
>   then I recommend that you threshold the negated image instead of
>   trying to work out the right threshold value to use (one less than
>   IM's current 'MaxRGB'), a value that is dependant on your specific
>   IM's compile time in Quality, or 'Q' setting.
>
> `convert logo.png -negate -threshold 0 -negate threshold_white.gif`

Source [Threshold Dithering Methods](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#threshold)

Comment: It does work!  Now, I have to figure out how to remove the pixelation noise of the "close to white".  Thank you for your response.